# How to use different fix point types in mathematical operations in Ada?

Tags: ada

For the program at the end I get the following error messages from gnat:

```
test2.adb:23:61: error: invalid operand types for operator "-"
test2.adb:23:61: error: left operand has type "Gain_Type" defined at line 11
test2.adb:23:61: error: right operand has type "Offset_Type" defined at line 12
```

Unfortunately I did not find a good example how to resolve this in a way resulting in speed optimized code for rather small embedded targets.

Always casting everything to the biggest type does not make that much sense I feel.
What is the best way to do that/ isn't there a good reference existing how to efficiently use fixed point for a bit more complicated mathematical problems?

```ada
procedure Test2 is
   Adc_Width   : constant Positive := 10;
   Adc_Delta   : constant Float    := 2.0**(-Adc_Width);
   Adc_Mod   : constant    := 2**Adc_Width;
   Error_Delta : constant          := 2.0**(-1);
   Gain_Min    : constant Float    := 1.0 - 2.0 * Adc_Delta;
   Gain_Max    : constant Float    := 1.0 + 2.0 * Adc_Delta;
   Offset_Min  : constant Float    := -0.5 * Adc_Delta;
   Offset_Max  : constant Float    := 2.0 * Adc_Delta;
   type Gain_Type is delta Adc_Delta * Error_Delta range Gain_Min .. Gain_Max;
   type Offset_Type is
      delta Adc_Delta * Error_Delta range Offset_Min .. Offset_Max;
   type Adc_Encoded_Type is mod Adc_Mod with
      Size => 16;
   subtype Adc_Value_Type is natural range 0 .. Adc_Encoded_Type'Modulus - 1;
   type Adc_Delta_Type is delta Adc_Delta range 0.0 .. 1.0 - Adc_Delta;
   function Compensate
    (Adc : in Adc_Encoded_Type; Gain : in Gain_Type; Offset : in Offset_Type)
     return Adc_Delta_Type
   is
   begin
      return Adc_Delta_Type (((Adc_Value_Type (Adc) * Gain) - Offset) / Adc_Mod);
   end Compensate;
begin
end Test2;
```

Comment: Ada does not allow mixed types operation. Any language allows mixed types operation is less than safe. By the way, Ada is named after lady Ada Lovelace. It is not an acronym.

Comment: @AnhVo I have already read that it does not select/ create a fixed point data type with sufficient range and resolution which would ensure that it does not loose information itself when doing fixed point arithmetic. However, I also did not want to go with the maximum and have to do this always manually to then throw resolution away at the end. I hoped that there is a elegant solution.
Thanks for the correction, I have edited the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Gain_Type and Offset_Type are physically compatible, you could make them subtypes of a common type since they have the same delta.

```
procedure Test2 is
   Adc_Width   : constant := 10;
   Adc_Delta   : constant := 2.0**(-Adc_Width);
   Adc_Mod     : constant := 2**Adc_Width;
   Error_Delta : constant := 2.0**(-1);
   Gain_Min    : constant := 1.0 - 2.0 * Adc_Delta;
   Gain_Max    : constant := 1.0 + 2.0 * Adc_Delta;
   Offset_Min  : constant := -0.5 * Adc_Delta;
   Offset_Max  : constant := 2.0 * Adc_Delta;
   --
   type Super_Type is delta Adc_Delta * Error_Delta range -1.0 .. 2.0;
   subtype Gain_Type   is Super_Type range Gain_Min .. Gain_Max;
   subtype Offset_Type is Super_Type range Offset_Min .. Offset_Max;
   --
   type Adc_Encoded_Type is mod Adc_Mod with
      Size => 16;
   subtype Adc_Value_Type is natural range 0 .. Adc_Encoded_Type'Modulus - 1;
   type Adc_Delta_Type is delta Adc_Delta range 0.0 .. 1.0 - Adc_Delta;
   function Compensate
    (Adc : in Adc_Encoded_Type; Gain : in Gain_Type; Offset : in Offset_Type)
     return Adc_Delta_Type
   is
   begin
      return Adc_Delta_Type (((Adc_Value_Type (Adc) * Gain) - Offset) / Adc_Mod);
   end Compensate;
begin
  null;
end Test2;
```

BTW, I have removed the types in the constants in order to remove rounding errors.